# define an indicator for overlapping time interval

Tags: r, dataframe

I have

```
 household       person     start time   end time
     1           1          07:45:00    21:45:00
     1           2          09:45:00    17:45:00
     1           3          22:45:00    23:45:00
     1           4          08:45:00    01:45:00
     1           1          23:50:00    24:00:00
     2           1          07:45:00    21:45:00
     2           2          016:45:00   22:45:00
```

I want to find a column to find overlapping time between family members.

The indicator is: if a person's start and end time has intersection with another member's is 1 otherwise 0

In the above example first family, the time of first, second and forth persons have intersection so indicator is 1 and third and fifth rows doesn't have intersection with non of the other people in the household.

output:

```
 household       person     start time   end time      overlap
      1           1          07:45:00    21:45:00           1
      1           2          09:45:00    17:45:00           1
      1           3          22:45:00    23:45:00           0
      1           4          08:45:00    01:45:00           1
      1           1          23:50:00    24:00:00           0     
      2           1          07:45:00    21:45:00           1
      2           2          016:45:00   22:45:00           1
```

data with dput format:

```
         structure(list(SAMPN = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), PERNO = c(1, 
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1), arr = structure(c(30300, 35280, 37200, 32400, 
         34200, 39600), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), 
         dep = structure(c(34200, 36300, 61800, 33600, 37800, 50400
), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs")), class =  c("grouped_df", 
        "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
          SAMPN = 1:2, PERNO = c(1, 1), .rows = list(1:3, 4:6)), row.names = c(NA, 
       -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df = structure(list(SAMPN = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
     PERNO = c(1:3, 1:3), arr = structure(c(30300, 35280, 37200, 32400, 
              34200, 39600), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), 
     dep = structure(c(34200, 36300, 61800, 33600, 37800, 50400), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs")), class =  c("grouped_df","tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(SAMPN = 1:2, PERNO = c(1, 1), .rows = list(1:3, 4:6)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Then, I added:

```
df %>% group_by(SAMPN) %>% 
   mutate(
     arr_min = mapply(function(x) min(arr[-x]), 1:n()),  
     dep_max = mapply(function(x) max(dep[-x]), 1:n()),
     overlap = ifelse(arr<arr_min | dep>dep_max, 0, 1)
   )
```

You will get:

```
  SAMPN PERNO arr    dep    arr_min dep_max overlap
  <int> <int> <time> <time>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1     1 08:25  09:30    35280   61800       0
2     1     2 09:48  10:05    30300   61800       1
3     1     3 10:20  17:10    30300   36300       0
4     2     1 09:00  09:20    34200   50400       0
5     2     2 09:30  10:30    32400   50400       1
6     2     3 11:00  14:00    32400   37800       0
```

You basically compare the current `arr` and `dep` with `arr_min` (`min(arr)` value excluding the current case) and `dep_max` (`max(dep)` excluding the current case).

Comment: I have a question for you, is there any way to determine who has overlap with who? for example if the indicator is 1, who has overlap with him?

Comment: this is over my head. I thought it was answered previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57813974/finding-overlapping-time-between-start-time-and-end-time-of-individuals-in-a-gro

Answer (score 0):

**Tidyverse solution**

Here's a solution in tidyverse syntax. The basic idea is the same. We perform a many to many merge matching on household (`sampn` in your current example data) and remove the cases of comparing a person to themself (`perno`). We check for overlaps, then collapse to a single record per household and person. Note that this code will error if all records have the same perno.

```
compare <- 
  df %>% 
  left_join(df %>% 
              rename(compare_PERNO = PERNO, 
                     compare_arr = arr,
                     compare_dep = dep), by = ("SAMPN")) %>% 
  filter(PERNO != compare_PERNO) %>% 
  mutate(overlap = arr <= compare_dep & dep >= compare_arr) %>% 
  group_by(SAMPN, PERNO) %>% 
  summarize(overlap = max(overlap))
```

**SQL Solution with household grouping**

Grouping the data by household actually makes this problem slightly easier. Again, I'm using SQL to solve it. In the inner SQL statement I do a many to many merge matching all members of a household to all other members, I remove any cases of matching a person to themself. Then, in the outer SQL statement we reduce to one record per household and person, which indicates if they ever overlapped.

```
df = data.frame(
  household = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,2)),
  person = c(1:5, 1:2),
  start_time=as.Date(c("2017-05-31","2018-01-14", "2019-02-03", "2018-01-19", "2019-04-17",
                       "2018-02-03", "2018-03-03"), 
                     format="%Y-%m-%d"),
  end_time=as.Date(c("2018-01-17", "2018-01-20", "2019-04-15", "2018-02-20", "2019-05-17", 
                     "2019-03-03", "2019-03-03"), 
                   format="%Y-%m-%d"))

library(sqldf)
compare <- sqldf(
  "
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT L.* , 
      CASE WHEN L.start_time <= R.end_time AND L.end_time >= R.start_time THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END AS overlap
    FROM df as L
    LEFT JOIN df as R ON L.household = R.household
    WHERE L.person != R.person 
  ) 
  GROUP BY household, person
  HAVING overlap = MAX(overlap)
  "
)
```

**SQL Solution without household grouping**

This is an SQL solution to your problem. I do a keyless many to many merge to compare each row to every other row (but dont compare a row to itself), then I parse the big data frame down to a single record per ID that records whether any matches were found. Your data isn't quite a reprex (use the `dput` function in R), so I used an example dataset I had lying around. If you have trouble adapting this to your exact data, post reproducible data and I can help you out.

```
df = data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  start_time=as.Date(c("2017-05-31","2018-01-14", "2018-02-03"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),
  end_time=as.Date(c("2018-01-17", "2018-01-20", "2018-04-17"), format="%Y-%m-%d"))


library(sqldf)
compare <- sqldf(
  "
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT L.* , 
      CASE WHEN L.start_time <= R.end_time AND L.end_time >= R.start_time THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END AS overlap
    FROM df as L
    CROSS JOIN df as R 
    WHERE L.id != R.id 
  ) 
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING overlap = MAX(overlap)
  "
)
```

Comment: I need to compare each row by some other rows in that household. I don't compare people in different household together.

Comment: Oops, forgot that you have the extra layer of blocking the individuals by households.  Can you edit your question to include the `dput` of your data so I have the full frame to work with?

Comment: I don't know what is dput data, let me to search it then I'll edit

Comment: dput is an r function that returns a text representation of an object. So if you run `dput(mydataset)` the output will be something that you can paste into stack overflow and other people can copy into their R session.

Comment: please see edit, thanks

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this example data doesnt match the earlier problem statement, I only see one identifying variable `sampn` that always has a value of 1

Comment: I created some example data that should match and posted another solution. Let me know if you have more questions

Comment: I edited again the example for u

Comment: and it should be grouped by household not person

Comment: your current example doesn't include any overlaps. In the inner sql statement I merge on household, that ensures that comparisons only happen within a household. The outer group by statement is used to reduce the data frame back down to one row per person.

Comment: I wonder `PERNO = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)` should be `PERNO = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)`