# time comparison with the help of another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I posted a similar question here [Determining at most 1 hour time difference between car and non-car mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57838735/determining-at-most-1-hour-time-difference-between-car-and-non-car-mode)

but since I didn't get the answer I change the output format to make it simpler. (not sure even its simpler or not)

I have

```
 household       person     time           mode
      1           1          07:45:00        non-car
      1           1          09:05:00         car
      1           2          08:10:00         non-car
      1           3          22:45:00       non-car
      1           4          08:30:00         car
      2           1          07:45:00        non-car
      2           2          16:45:00       car
```

I want to find a column to find if non-car mode is at most 1 hour before a car mode in each family.

In the above example first family, the time of first person is 1 hour before person 4, so in new column 4 infant of first person and 1 infant of 4th person.
output:

```
 household       person     time           mode          household       person     time           mode      
      1           1          07:45:00        non-car        1           4          08:30:00        car                  
      1           2          08:10:00        non-car        1           4          08:30:00        car         
      1           3          22:45:00        non-car       NA          NA           NA            NA               
      1           2          08:10:00        non-car        1           1          09:05:00        car               
      2           1          07:45:00        non-car        NA          NA.          NA            NA                   
      2           2          16:45:00        car            NA          NA.          NA            NA
```

no intersection with other family member is NA or whatever like 0

Basically I just need to check if a driver is available for a non-driver or not. a driver is available for a non-driver if:

```
   the non-driver person's time is at most 1 hour before driver.
```

so in each household I need to do this comparison. and match driver and non-driver if they can travel together. So if you think you can do that with another output please feel free to do that.
If you think it can not be done with R plz let me know I will think how I can change problem.
Thanks for your time

Comment: If it is hard, forget about car and non-car just compare all member together.

Comment: It looks like you have three very similar questions. Can you please edit & clarify the first one instead of adding more with essentially the same question?

Comment: @JonSpring actually they look the same but they are different, I thought maybe someone can answer one of them. If I get 1 answer for one of them I will remove similar question