# Pairing rows which have at most one hour's time difference

Tags: r, dataframe

Sorry if I ask a question in different way, I just need to solve my problem. I've posted here [time comparison with the help of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841683/time-comparison-with-the-help-of-another-column)

Now I want to make it simpler in order to some one give me answer.

I posted a similar question here [Determining at most 1 hour time difference between car and non-car mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57838735/determining-at-most-1-hour-time-difference-between-car-and-non-car-mode)

but since I didn't get the answer I change the output format to make it simpler. (not sure even its simpler or not)

I have

```
 household       person     time           
      1           1          07:45:00       
      1           1          09:05:00         
      1           2          08:10:00         
      1           3          22:45:00       
      1           4          08:30:00         
      2           1          07:45:00       
      2           2          16:45:00
```

I want to find a column to find if persons in each household have close trip with respect of each other.

I want to pair them if one row is at most 1 hour before another trip.

In the above example first family, the time of first person is 1 hour before person 4,
output:

```
 household       person     time                   household       person     time                
      1           1          07:45:00              1           4          08:30:00            
      1           1          07:45:00              1           2          08:10:00        
      1           2          08:10:00              1           4          08:30:00          
      1           2          08:10:00              1           1          09:05:00    
      1           4          08:30:00              1           1          09:05:00    
      1           3          22:45:00              NA          NA           NA                          
      1           2          08:10:00              1           1          09:05:00                       
      2           1          07:45:00              NA          NA.          NA                              
      2           2          16:45:00              NA          NA.          NA
```

no intersection with other family member is NA or whatever like 0

Just notice that in the above pair first part's time is smaller than second part. but the order of rows does not matter

Comment: Rather than asking the very similar question again and again, you should use the editing option which gives you a chance to update it. Additionally, including your effort (the codes you wrote already for trying to solve your problem) increases your chance to get an answer.

Comment: @maydin I thought maybe other output get some solution,

Answer (score 0):

Recreating your data as follows:

```
household <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2)
person <- c(1,1,2,3,4,1,2)
time <- strptime(c('07:45:00','09:05:00','08:10:00','22:45:00','08:30:00','07:45:00','16:45:00'), format = '%H:%M:%S')
df <- data.frame(household = household, person = person, time = time)
```

You can then merge df with itself on the 'household' column, then filter for the cases where the persons are not the same and the times are within 1 hour. You can use the difftime() function with units of 'hours' to get the time difference:

```
df.merge <- merge(df, df, by = 'household')
df.merge <- df.merge[(df.merge$person.x != df.merge$person.y) & 
                         df.merge$time.x < df.merge$time.y & 
                         difftime(df.merge$time.y, df.merge$time.x, units = 'hours') <= 1,]
```

This will give you the desired set without the combinations which are outside the 1 hour limit. If you do want the NA for unmatched, then we can do an anti-join (from the dplyr package) as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
# rename the key columns of df.merge for easy join
colnames(df.merge) <- c('household', 'person', 'time', 'person.y', 'time.y')
# unmatched persons
unmatched_df <- anti_join(df, df.merge, by=c('household','person'))
# final set of matched and unmatched persons
bind_rows(df.merge, unmatched_df)
```

Of course, you'll have problems with the above code if the times are on different days.